# psql: Default up/down arrows to use incremental history search

Tags: shell, psql

I'm trying to make the up/down keys in psql work the same way they do in bash, as per this config:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/73523

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Ie, whenever I type some characters and hit up or down, it only shows me entries from my history which match those characters.

I have found the following question which explains how to trigger incremental-history-search in psql:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63453/is-there-a-psql-equivalent-of-bashs-reverse-search-history

However, that still requires me to hit ctrl-R in order to trigger it. Is there any way for me to configure the up/down keys in psql to default to incrmental history search?

I am on Mac, using psql (11.1, server 10.5)